# rbash - how to allow some commands and fix autocomplete?

Tags: bash

I need to have restricted shell for some users.

This is achieved via:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/rbash
sudo useradd test1 -s /bin/rbash
```

The new user is fine, by default it lands on a restricted shell, but I find it annoying that `cd` is not allowed, autocompletion does not work, like:

```
test1@hostone [ ~ ]$ cd /
-rbash: cd: restricted
test1@hostone [ ~ ]$ sudo cd /con<TAB pressed here>-rbash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
bash: _upvars: `-a3': invalid number specifier
-rbash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
bash: _upvars: `-a0': invalid number specifier
^C
test1@hostone [ ~ ]$ sudo cd /config
sudo: cd: command not found
test1@hostone [ ~ ]$ docker logs ag<TAB pressed here>-rbash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
-rbash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
bash: _upvars: `-a3': invalid number specifier
-rbash: /dev/null: restricted: cannot redirect output
bash: _upvars: `-a0': invalid number specifier
^C
test1@hostone [ ~ ]$
```

How do I allow individual commands, like `cd`? How should I fix the auto completion?

If you wonder the OS is Photon OS.

Comment: yup, yup I know about rbash not being the sharpest tool, it is rather a test, an experiment, a study on restricted shells. I picked it because it is the first hit..

ok, be it a design decision to restrict cd, the user has very valid use-case with cd, and cd is not going to be the only command that has to be allowed - how do I do that?

Comment: or would you recommend another restricted shell?

Comment: thanks. but for the same of my curiosity, is there a way to allow command in a restricted shell? (if you wish you can sum-up your comments in an answer, so that I can properly upvote?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as of `bash` version 5.0.3, `rbash` is still insecure - it doesn't disable Ctrl/C during execution of `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, which means that it's trivially possible to break out to a shell prompt before the default `$PATH` has been suitably restricted. At this point it is easy to execute (say) `dash` and then `bash` to get a clean shell.

The `cd` command is denied by design. Read up on `rbash` (see `man bash` and search for `rbash`) to see the full details, but a shortened list includes this list of denied actions:

- changing directories with `cd`
- setting or unsetting the values of `SHELL`, `PATH`, `ENV`, or `BASH_ENV`
- specifying command names containing '/'
- redirecting output using the `>`, `>|`, `<>`, `>&`, `&>`, and `>>` redirection operators
- turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o restricted

Unfortunately, autocompletion runs in the user's context and redirects - or attempts to redirect - certain commands' output to `/dev/null`.

Other shells such as `rsh` (`sh`) correctly implement a lockdown during execution of `.profile` so that Ctrl/C is temporarily disabled, but the restriction on `cd` remains.

You say that you need `cd` to work. In this case you won't be able to use a restricted shell. You might be better off with a chroot environment, depending of course on your requirement. Alternatively, perhaps a script that performs the necessary task would be sufficient. If it can be placed into a directory accessed through `$PATH` then the user could use that script directly.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Much appreciated! :) A lot of people on the stackexchange have become bitter for one reason or another and does not see why they should help others, that's why your help is so valuable!

Comment: @gai-jin I'm sorry to hear you find that. I haven't noticed a bitterness on [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)